# Find the proper first item in a list by checking it only one time, and return the checking result

Tags: scala

There is a list of urls, like:

```
val urls = List("http://....", "http://....", "http://....", "http://....", ...)
```

Some urls are not accessible, and some one will return status `404`, `500`, etc.

And I have a function which can check if a url is accessible and also have status code `200`, and get the `ContentType` as well. The function is pretty expensive since it will visit the network and have read timeout of 10s.

```
case class GoodSite(url:String, contentType: String)

def checkUrl(url:String): Option[GoodSite] = {
    // visit the url, and get the response status code and content type
    if(responseCode==200) Some(GoodSite(url, contentType))
    else None
}
```

Now I want to check the url from the list one by one, and only get the first one which will return code 200, then return the content type.

I have two solutions:

```
urls.flatMap(checkUrl).headOption
```

and

```
urls.find(url => checkUrl(url)!=None).map(checkUrl(_))
```

But both of them are not good, because they will performs some unnecessary calls of `checkUrl` function.

Is there any good solution to make just call it only once?

Comment: I think that's how `find` works. How do you confirm it performs unnecessary call of `checkUrl`?

Comment: You can see there are two `checkUrl` calls in the 2nd solution, but only the first one is enough to get all the information I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both Eugene Zhulenev's and Kai Sternad's answer fulfill your original requirement. But I argue that you rethink about your problem.

Imagine the length of your `urls` is `N` and the kth url take `T(k)` time to check, what is the time that the sequential code takes to find the GoodSite? In the best case it will be `T(0)` if the first url is good. In the worse case it will be `T(0) + T(1) + ... + T(N-1)`, for both the case that `T(N-1)` is the only `GoodSite` and the case that no `GoodSite` exists.

My suggestion is to start checking all urls at the same time, **asynchronously**, and finish checking as soon as the first `GoodSite` is found. In every case that a `GoodSite` exists, it will take `min(T(0), T(1), ..., T(N-1))` and if no `GoodSite` exists, the time is `max(T(0), T(1), ..., T(N-1))`.

The following is a piece of working code demonstrating my point, using spray-client(1.3.1-20140423_2.11).

```
  import akka.actor.ActorSystem
  import scala.util.{Failure, Success}
  import spray.http.HttpHeaders.`Content-Type`
  import scala.concurrent.Future
  import spray.http._
  import spray.client.pipelining._

  implicit val system = ActorSystem()
  import system.dispatcher

  val pipeline = sendReceive
  case class GoodSite(url: String, contentType: Option[`Content-Type`])

  def url2GoodSite(url: String): Future[GoodSite] = {
    pipeline(Get(url)).map { response =>
        response.status match {
          case StatusCodes.OK => GoodSite(url, response.header[`Content-Type`])
          case _ => throw new RuntimeException("bad site")
        }
    }
  }

  val data = List("http://www.yahoo.com", "http://www.sina.com.cn", "http://www.oschina.net")

  val result = Future.find(data.map(url2GoodSite))(_ => true)

  result.onComplete {
    case Success(good) =>
      // use the fastest GoodSite
      println(good)
      system.shutdown()
    case Failure(e) =>
      // no GoodSite found
      println("No good site found.")
      system.shutdown()
  }
```

Using spray-client or another library is not important. The implementation detail of `def url2GoodSite(url: String): Future[GoodSite]` is not important. The key point is that it returns `Future[GoodSite]` instead of `Option[GoodSite]`. Whenever dealing with network io, think about this transition. Consider this the first step to catch up with the [reactive](http://www.reactivemanifesto.org/) trend.

Comment: Thanks for the great solution which gives me some new ideas!

Answer (score 2):

After you take iterator from your list all operations are lazy evaluated:

```
  val urls = List("http://google.com", "http://amazon.com", "http::/yahoo.com")

  case class GoodSite(url:String, contentType: String)

  val cnt = new AtomicInteger(0)

  def checkUrl(url:String): Option[GoodSite] = {
    println(s"Check url: $url")
    val (responseCode, contentType) = getResponseCodeAndContentType(url)
    if(responseCode==200 && cnt.getAndIncrement == 1)
      Some(GoodSite(url, contentType))
    else None
  }

  val firstGood = urls.iterator.map(checkUrl).collectFirst {
    case Some(good) => good
  }

  println(firstGood)
```

Comment: `cnt` is not necessary for this is a sequential iterator not a parallel one.

Comment: @xiefei, you mean we don't need a `AtomicInteger`, actually we need a `MutableInteger` or a `var`?

Answer (score 2):

You could also convert your list of urls to a stream and then drop while you don't have a good site:

```
  urls.toStream.map(checkUrl).dropWhile(_.isEmpty).headOption
```